# Combinations of elements in a dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

Suppose I have a Ordered Dict of the form

```
d = OrderedDict([('x1', ['x1_0', 'x1_1']), ('x2', ['x2_0', 'x2_1','x2_2'])])
```

How do I get combinations of the form

```
[('x1_0', 'x2_0'),('x1_0', 'x2_1'),('x1_0', 'x2_2'),('x1_1', 'x2_0'),('x1_1', 'x2_1'),('x1_1', 'x2_2')]
```

P.S. Here I am showing the result for only two variables here but I am looking for a more general code. Also feel free to use as many tools as possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want something like

```
import itertools
x = list(itertools.product(*d.values()))
```

does this leave out anything you desire...?

Comment: @PalashAhuja, always happy to help -- remember to **accept** the A when enough time has passed to let you!-)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following:

```
import collections
from itertools import product
d = collections.OrderedDict([('x1', ['x1_0', 'x1_1']), ('x2', ['x2_0',     'x2_1','x2_2'])])
poss = [(k,v) if v else (k,) for k,v in d.items()]
list(product(*poss))
```

Output:

```
 [('x1', 'x2'),
 ('x1', ['x2_0', 'x2_1', 'x2_2']),
 (['x1_0', 'x1_1'], 'x2'),
 (['x1_0', 'x1_1'], ['x2_0', 'x2_1', 'x2_2'])]
```

It gave me a combination, not exactly in the form of your example, but in case someone needs a different combination.